# Include Right-to-Left text in youtrack issues

Tags: youtrack

I'm currently using YouTrack cloud service and I'm interested in including Right-to-Left text snippets inside certain issues while keeping the majority of the interface and default text direction in LTR.

Until recently I was able to start such a ticket with the following HTML snippet:

```
<span style="direction: rtl;">
```

And it worked decently well. I now see this is no longer working including older issues that displayed properly in the past. I assume something changed due to a recent update.

I've tried similar HTML snippets (using `div`, `dir=rtl`) but none seem to work.

I'm wondering is there's a current solution, if *I don't wish to completely change the interface* to RTL but only text in certain issues.

Comment: `&#x2067;`…`&#x2069;`?

Comment: @user3840170 Thanks, this doesn't seem to work unfortunately :(

Comment: It was never really supported explicitly. So in case, if it worked in some version, it was accidental. Here's the feature request to support and maintain this functionality: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-70594/

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue. It since been marked as fixed, reopened and marked as fixed again... hopefully it'll move something with the devs

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can download the chrome extension I developed for  that case, it's free:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtrack-rtl/abgihmdajkjolifdbkboickopfhcefhe

Comment: Thanks, but I think installing a chrome extension for RTL support in youtrack is an overkill and a security risk I rather avoid.